# Is it illegal to make a Twitter bot that replies to every person mentioning a particular brand? (non-threatening)

Tags: united-kingdom

I have an incident with a particular company where my meal had an object in it.

The company is refusing responsibility so I was wondering if it's illegal to use a twitter bot that replies everyone mentioning the particular brand with a picture of my meal containing the object in it?

Something along the lines of "Did you know that your meal from BLAH brands can also contain this [object]" and a picture of the object.

Answer (score 2):

It wont be illegal. Might be against twitter's spam rules.

But not illegal. So long as the company really did put that object in your meal.

Comment: Do some more research - accessing computer systems without permission (i.e. against terms of service) is illegal.

Comment: Twitter has a bot api. Twitter bots are permitted by twitter